# How to change the format of autocomplete in Sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I installed the Emmet plugin in the Sublime text 3, and when I type 'function' in JavaScript syntax, the editor will autocomplete it into 
`function function_name (argument) {
    // body...
}`, but I need to delete the space between the function_name and the argument.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a built-in Sublime snippet, and is not related to Emmet. To override the default, perform the following steps:

1. Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` to open a file explorer menu in your ST3 `Packages` directory.
2. Create a new directory called `JavaScript`.
3. Create a new file in Sublime with the following content:

   ```xml
   <snippet>
       <content><![CDATA[function ${1:function_name}(${2:argument}) {
       ${0:// body...}
   }]]></content>
       <tabTrigger>fun</tabTrigger>
       <scope>source.js</scope>
       <description>Function</description>
   </snippet>
   ```
4. Save the file as `Packages/JavaScript/function-(fun).sublime-snippet` - make sure you use this exact name, or it won't override the built-in snippet.
5. Restart Sublime (just in case), and now when you're writing JavaScript and type `fun`<kbd>Tab</kbd> it will display:

   ```js
   function function_name(argument) {
       // body...
   }
   ```

Comment: where can i view a description of the syntax used here? I can't seem to find it (ex. ${1:function_name}

Comment: [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/snippets.html) and [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can make this even easier by installing [Package Resource Viewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer)

1. Press `Ctrl-Shift-P` to bring up `Package Control`
2. type `install` hit `Enter` to bring up `Package Control: Install Package`
3. type `PackageResourceViewer` hit `Enter`

---

To modify the Javascript `function-(fun)` snippet:

1. Bring up Package Control again `(Ctrl+Shift+P)`
2. type `ope` hit `Enter` to bring up `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
3. type `js` hit `Enter` to browse the `Javascript` package
4. type `fun`& select `function-(fun)` and edit to your heart's content :)